# Creating User specified number of threads in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm doing a download application for android. The downloading part is now successfully implemented and its working.
What I need is to download the file parallel in segments. To be more clear, if the user specify 8 segments, I want to create 8 Threads and do the downloading.
So in what way will I be able to create 8 threads dynamically? Also as I'm doing this for an phone how will I be able to maintain the memory consumption at a minimum level?
I have not worked with threads before, so I hope you can help me with this. Thank you for your time! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most efficient way to create a fixed number of threads is to use the [ExecutorService](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html):

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
```

It's basically a fixed-size thread pool that takes a lot of the management burden from the developer.

**Edit**: So your flow should be something like this:

First, define your thread task class (each thread will execute the `call` method of its own task):

```
class ThreadTask implements Callable<Object> {

    public Object call() {
        // execute download
        ...
        return result;
    }
}
```

If you want to pass any parameters to the tasks, put some private fields in the class above and pass them through a constructor. Also, you can return any type from `call`, just change the type in the `implements Callable<...>` part.

When you want to fire off the threads, create the pool and submit the tasks:

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
List<Future<Object>> results = new ArrayList<Future<Object>>();

// submit tasks
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    results.add(exec.submit(new ThreadTask()));
}

...

// stop the pool from accepting new tasks
exec.shutdown();

// wait for results
for(Future<Object> result: results) {
    Object obj = result.get();
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you, but could you please elaborate the answer, explaining where I should place my logic...

Comment: @Tudor: results.add(exec.submit(new Task()); there is an error in this line.

Comment: @user1122359: Yeah, sorry, I didn't close the paranthesis correctly. Fixed now.

Comment: @Tudor:  No, I tried with the paranthesis. But its givin me "Task cannot be resolved to a type" error...

Comment: Oh I guess it should be results.add(exec.submit(new ThreadTask())); isnt it?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `ExecutorService`, in particular [Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int i)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29), this is an excellent way to handle threads in a system friendly matter.